# filtering an array and keeping a reference to the index from original array?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to filter an array of answers for the incorrect answers, and then only removing two of them from the original array.

**Code:**

```
var answers = [
   {text: "foo",  isCorrect: false},
   {text: "bar",  isCorrect: true},
   {text: "foo2", isCorrect: false},
   {text: "bar2", isCorrect: false}
]
var inCorrect = answers.filter((v, i) => !v.isCorrect);
```

Choose two random answers from the `inCorrect` array and get the index from the answer array.

Comment: `i` is the index in your `filter` callback.

Comment: How is your data getting bound to your view? What determines if an answer is "disabled" or not? Do the answers have an `active` or `disabled` property on them or something that the UI is looking at?

Comment: @mhodges yes im passing them down as props to a child component <Answer isSelected={false} isCorrect={false} ... /> etc.

Comment: @BrainYoung Okay, see if my solution is what you were looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the correct answer along with two random incorrect answers, you can use the following code. This will leave the original array intact, and return references to the objects in the original array.

```js
var answers = [
   {answer: "foo",  isCorrect: false},
   {answer: "bar",  isCorrect: true},
   {answer: "foo2", isCorrect: false},
   {answer: "bar2", isCorrect: false}
]
function getRandom (ceiling) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (ceiling || 1));
}
function fiftyFifty (answers) {
    var correct = answers.find(answer => answer.isCorrect);
    var incorrectAnswers = answers.filter(answer => !answer.isCorrect);
    // grab n answers unless there are less than n incorrect answers to choose from
    var numberOfIncorrects = Math.min(2, incorrectAnswers.length);
    var incorrectsToUse = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfIncorrects; i++) {
      let randomIndex = getRandom(incorrectAnswers.length);
      // splice elem out of array so it doesn't get randomly selected twice
      incorrectsToUse.push(incorrectAnswers.splice(randomIndex, 1)[0]);
    }
    return [correct].concat(incorrectsToUse);
}

console.log(fiftyFifty(answers));
console.log(fiftyFifty(answers));
console.log(fiftyFifty(answers));
```

Comment: Thanks @mhodges, close! I need get two incorrect answers. rather than one correct and one incorrect. :)

Comment: @BrainYoung Oh, gotcha. Easy fix. Standby

Comment: @BrainYoung Updated. Not sure how you want the output, though. Do you want them in a single array, or do you want them in an object with `{correct: obj, incorrect: [obj, obj]}` or do you want the incorrect answers nested in their own array like `[correct, [incorrect, incorrect2]]`?

Comment: @BrainYoung See my most recent update. I made it dynamic so you can return as many incorrect answers as you'd like (up to the length of the incorrectAnswers array)

Answer (score 1):

Does just assigning back to `answers` work?

```js
var answers = [
   {val : "foo",  isCorrect: false},
   {val : "bar",  isCorrect: true},
   {val : "foo2", isCorrect: false},
   {val : "bar2", isCorrect: false}
];
answers = answers.filter(v => v.isCorrect);

console.log(answers);
```

Comment: No, changing the answers array changes the state!

Comment: @BrainYoung I'm confused.. you want to maintain the reference to answers, remove incorrect answers from `answers`, while not modifying the `answers` array?

Comment: I want to have an new array of incorrect answers(3 answers) and then choose 2 random elements from those 3. those 2 answers will be faded out in the UI, so answers can't be changed.

Comment: @BrainYoung "Who wants to be a millionaire" 50/50 lifeline style?

Comment: @BrainYoung, are you using something that automatically binds your data to the UI? Normally modifying something in memory has no affect on the DOM.

Comment: exactly @mhodges

Comment: @AndréDion I'm assuming React or Angular since the word `state` was used, but I could be wrong

Comment: @BrainYoung, you should update your question with these details. They're pertinent.

Comment: @AndréDion yeah sorry my bad, Just changed the question.